# Accessing parent element in javascript without creating handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it posible to access the variable defined in parent function without creating the handler for it ?

So basically what i need is something like below.

```
var g=100;

(function f()
{ 

 var g=200;

 (function()
  {
    var g=300;

    console.log(g);            //300
    console.log(window.g);     //100
    console.log( ?? ) // how should i get value of g as 200 here ??

  })();

}();
```

Please note here that i dont want to create handler here. If i have only one function, and i want to access parent variable(same varible present in the current function) inside the function then i can use window.[variablename]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use different variable names, otherwise the variable from the parent scope will be masked by the one in the internal scope.

Overriding variable names between scopes is **bad practice** and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Data Hiding. You can't access outer block data without help from a handler.

Answer (score 1):

I know that there is a chosen answer already but I will put in my 2 cents in case it is useful for you.

Maybe something like this is what you want:

```
new (function () {
    this.msg = "hello 1";
    console.log(this.msg);

    new (function (parent) {
        this.msg = "hello 2";
        console.log(this.msg); // hello 2
        console.log(parent.msg); // hello 1
    })(this)
})()
```

You can keep creating inner scopes with the `new` keyword to achieve this tree-like structure of scopes where you can keep accessing the parent scope (which was also created using the `new` keyword.

Comment: Yes this will also work provided parent function is passed as an arguement. Thanks Shafeen.